# How to extract json array in presto?

Tags: json, amazon-athena, presto

I have a json data set like as below:

```
    {
        "eventType": "Send",
        "mail": {
                [{
                    "name": "From",
                    "value": "youraddress@example.com"
                }, {
                    "name": "To",
                    "value": "success@simulator.amazonses.com"
                }, {
                    "name": "Subject",
                    "value": "Bounced Like a Bad Check"
                },
                ...
                {
                    "name": "nameN",
                    "value": "N"
                }
            ]
    }
```

I am trying to write a query using AWS Athena ( which is Presto underneath) to extract values like:

```
eventType, name1,name2,name3, ... nameN
Send, From, To, Subject, ...., nameN
```

I am struggling in extracting this nested json.

Comment: Can you clarify that the data same is the raw data and you are trying to define the table, or it is a cell from an already defined table row you are trying to query into with presto?

Comment: your json is not consistent to define a row. So you might have to write your own serdeser.